# question about "es sheim" in kriash shma

Tags: prayer-book

I've always been a little confused by the way that the blessings before the shma are broken up. In case youre not aware, the section "es sheim" is the second half of a sentence that belongs to the section right before it. In most siddurs that i've used, there is a section break and an indication to wait for the chazzan in between.

why was this done this way? its just confusing to cut a sentence in half, so why do we do this?